# ASP.NET how to get top 10 from table where certain column is empty

Tags: asp.net

I have a ASP.NET project which returns data from a sql serer table. code like this:

```
  private dtsdbEntities _db = new dtsdbEntities();
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(_db.IPR_CompanyGen.ToList());
    }
```

how to get top 10 from table where isnull(CompanyName,'') = ''?

Comment: _db.IPR_CompanyGen.Where(c=>c.CompanyName == null).Take(10).ToList()

Comment: yes works. thanks much. can u post as answer so i can mark it my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should filter the results using a Linq query. Use the [Where method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where?view=netcore-3.1) and then take the top ten using the [Take method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.take?view=netcore-3.1):

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View(_db.IPR_CompanyGen.Where(c => c.CompanyName == null).Take(10).ToList());
}
```